# Editing a specific value in a csv text file through C programming

Tags: c, csv, copy, scanf, file-pointer

I'm trying to make a function that updates my csv text file.
The text file I have already has data inside it. I just want to change one of the values in one of the selected lines of data. I kind of confused on what to do here. When I try to print out the newInventory.numInstock it gives me the memory address. How can I get it to show me the text file values? I know I need to read the old file then copy what I need to a new file. Can someone help me out with this please.

My question is how do I get it to modify the numInStock? I want to be able to change that with this function.

```
/*here's my structure*/

struct inventory_s
{
    int productNumber;
    float mfrPrice;
    float retailPrice;
    int numInStock;// 4th column
    char liveInv;
    char productName[PRODUCTNAME_SZ +1];
};

/* My text file looks something like: */
1000,1.49,3.79,10,0,Fish Food
2000,0.29,1.59,100,1,AngelFish
2001,0.09,0.79,200,1,Guppy
5000,2.40,5.95,10,0,Dog Collar Large
6000,49.99,129.99,3,1,Dalmation Puppy

/*Here's my function so far*/

int updateStock(void)
{
    struct inventory_s newInventory;
    int productNumber;
    char line[50];

    FILE* originalFile = fopen("stuff.txt", "r"); //opens and reads file
    FILE* NewFile = fopen("stuffCopy.txt", "w"); //opens and writes file
    if(originalFile == NULL || NewFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open data file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf(" Please enter the product number to modify:");
    scanf(" %i", &productNumber);

    printf("Current value is %i; please enter new value:", &newInventory.numInStock );
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), originalFile) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d,%*f,%*f,%i", &newInventory.productNumber, &newInventory.mfrPrice, &newInventory.retailPrice, &newInventory.numInStock);
        if (productNumber == newInventory.productNumber)
        {
            fputs(line, NewFile);
            //fscanf(NewFile, "%s", &newInventory.productName);
            printf(" %i",newInventory.numInStock);
        }
    }

    fclose(originalFile);
    fclose(NewFile);
    // remove("stuff.txt");
    //rename("stuffCopy.txt", "inventory.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

So far I get it to print out the line that I'm trying to access. I need it to just access one of the values in the structure and show that one only. Then I need to change it to a new value from the user.

Comment: `numInStock` is 2nd column, not 4th column? (also line has comma?)

Comment: I'm confused with your comment. numInStock is in the fourth column position. They are separated by commas in the text file.

Comment: `sscanf(line, "%i %i", &newInventory.productNumber, &newInventory.numInStock)` does not take into account is that of them.

Comment: I see what you mean now. So do I need to scan all of them?

Comment: `"%i %i"` meant  1st column and 2nd column separate by spaces(and type is `int`).

Comment: change to like `"%d,%*f,%*f,%d"`. (`%*` is skip this element)

Comment: I changed it above. Does it look right? Also I trying to access the numInStock to display the current value before making any changes, but it keeps giving me the memory address.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry. It is only `productNumber` is to confirm the match. then read all for `newInventory` => update => write all `newInventory` instead of `fputs(line, NewFile);`

Comment: Sorry , but I'm confused with your comment. Do I need to change the fputs(line, NewFile);? I want to display the numInStock at the printf() prompt. What would I need to display it? I have &newInventory.numInStock as the variable pointer , but it just shows memory. So I have it wrong.

Comment: I post sample code as answer. I think you're want to have this kind of thing rather than simply want to output a single value.

Answer (score 1):

fix like this ( it will be your help.)

```
printf("Please enter the product number to modify:");
scanf("%i", &productNumber);

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), originalFile) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "%i", &newInventory.productNumber);
    if (productNumber == newInventory.productNumber)
    {
        sscanf(line, "%i,%f,%f,%i,%c,%[^\n]", &newInventory.productNumber, 
                                              &newInventory.mfrPrice,
                                              &newInventory.retailPrice,
                                              &newInventory.numInStock,
                                              &newInventory.liveInv,
                                              newInventory.productName);
        printf("Current value is %i; please enter new value:", newInventory.numInStock );
        scanf("%i", &newInventory.numInStock );
        fprintf(NewFile, "%i,%f,%f,%i,%c,%s\n",newInventory.productNumber, 
                                               newInventory.mfrPrice,
                                               newInventory.retailPrice,
                                               newInventory.numInStock,
                                               newInventory.liveInv,
                                               newInventory.productName);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs(line, NewFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to help me! I really appreciate it!